# Blogger sitemap for Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, sitemap, blogger

I'm developing a new Blogger Blog, and I'm about to send its first sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools. The thing is, I've found 2 articles about Blogger sitemaps, in which one is suggesting to send the sitemap through the url:

```
/sitemap.xml - http://datzo.blogspot.com/sitemap.xml
```

and the other one is suggesting to send it by: `/atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500`:

```
http://datzo.blogspot.com/atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500
```

([source](http://www.bloggertipstricks.com/submit-sitemap-google-webmaster-tools.html) < Article updated July 23 2015)

The thing is, I don't know which one to send and which one will be more efficient.

1. The first one seems to be more clean and right to the point.
2. But the second one though, seems to contain more information, but
   also another links from other websites and I'm concerned if this
   won't be **too much unnecessary information**. The second link also
   has the `max-results=500` on the URL, which is for the limit of
   pages indexed by Google I believe.

And now I'm on a dilemma, about which one to go with, because I don't understand much of sitemaps or SEO, so I need the help of you guys to help me chose the better one, and help me understand why.

(You can access the links to see the information outputted on both links)

Answer (score 1):

The first option was added about a year ago - see more about it here:  http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2014/11/blogs-to-have-automatically-generated.html

The other option still works AFAIK, and there are many advice articles out there written when the first option didn't exist, which therefore recommend the 2nd.

Answer (score -1):

The first option is the most correct. So max-results=500 it's RSS-Feed and updated it slower.